# Using Displays connected to PC from a Laptop via LAN

Tags: networking, laptop, multiple-monitors

So i regularly use my Work-Laptop(Win 11) at Home, there i have a beautiful triple screen setup on my PC(Win 10). The Laptop has a HDMI out, but that obviously only serves one display and i dont want to plug every screen into a hub or smth. I wondered, if there is a possibility to use all my PC Screens from the Laptop via LAN. To be clear, i dont want to sync the Clipboard or just move my mouse onto the other PC, i want my Laptop to host all displays(if he can handle it xD). Basically 3 extra displays on the Laptop like the Miracast wireless displays but without Wifi.

I've only come across solutions that act like a software KVM-Switch, thats not what im looking for.

Comment: What's the model number of that laptop?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible with Microsoft Remote Desktop. You just need to make sure both your laptop and PC are connected to the same network before proceeding with the instructions below.

**1. On the laptop search the start menu for "invitations" and open the following menu:**

[image]

**2. Under Remote Assistance make sure "Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer" is ticked. Also make sure "Allow remote connections to this computer" and the checkbox for Network Level Authentication is also ticked:**

Note: if you cannot change this options you will have to contact your system administrator and request it be turned on. It's often turned off by domain administrators to harden network/device security.

[image]

**3. On your PC go to the run menu (Windows Key + R) and type `mstsc`:**

[image]

**4. In the resulting window, enter the exact hostname of your laptop into the "Computer" field (if that does not work, you will have to enter the IP address instead). Followed by the hostname and a backslash and your laptop username inside the "Username" field. If your work laptop is connected to your company domain, you may need to enter the company domain name instead (`domainname\username`).**

[image]

**5. In the display tab make sure "Use all my monitors for the remote session" is ticked:**

[image]

**6. Now click on the connect button. If your PC has the correct hostname or IP address you should see a prompt to enter your password.**

[image]

You should now find your PC has remoted into your laptop and it should have successfully scaled to your triple screen PC setup.

**Tips:**

**How to find your laptop IP address**

Open a CMD window on your laptop and type `ipconfig`

[image]

You should see the ip address of your laptop is something like `192.168.x.x`

**How to save your MSTSC connection settings as a clickable shortcut on your PC desktop.**

Inside the mstsc window, after you have all the desired settings in place, you can click the "save as" button to create a shortcut on your desktop. Keep in mind, if you are remoting in using IP address then this could change (DHCP) the next time you connect that laptop to your home network.

[image]

To stop the IP from always changing you can log into your router admin page and manually set the laptop to have a static IP address instead. This process varies from router to router but most of them can all do this, you just need to check your router instruction manual to learn how.

**You may want to work remotely with the laptop lid closed without putting the laptop to sleep:**

- Click on start menu and search for “Lid”
- Click on “Choose what closing the lid does”
- For "when lid is closed" make sure “Do Nothing” is selected

Comment: Excellent instruction manual. Only problem is that if it is a company laptop RDP may not be enabled on the laptop and the user may not a have sufficient rights on the laptop to enable it himself.

Comment: Yes, indeed that is likely to be the main issue likely to be encountered. RDP in most cases is disabled on domain joined machines. It is where I've worked anyway! Thanks for adding that! Edited my answer to include this.